# Can't break any block in minecraft server Bukkit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have tried just about everything. I know I am op on my server and permissions are configured correctly to allow me to destroy blocks. I used to be able to do this but I cannot break blocks anymore on my own server!

I checked every single plugin and all of them allow me to break any block I want in any location. I restarted Minecraft many, many times and I still can't break blocks!

Comment: What did you change so that you couldn't break blocks? At what point did you notice that you couldn't?

Comment: Can you break blocks when you are an operator?

Comment: What happens when you try? Are you sent a message, or does it just not work? It could be something like a vanish plugin that doesn't allow you to place or break blocks when vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your permissions plugin.

They are known to do these kind of things.

(Just taking a wild guess :P)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem But i fixed it. Try doing /op [YourMinecraftUsername] If that doesn't work, try giving urself the "*" Permission.